# How to replace special character instead of dot symbol?

Tags: android, regex

In my project, I'm validating the regex pattern. For example: `[A-Z]?[1-9]`, this is the pattern. I want accept the answer like `A@9`, `A22` and `A#9`.

```
private String isValidRegex(String matcherInput, String regexInfix) {
    java.util.regex.Pattern pattern = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(PatternUtility.getInstance().convertToRegex(regexInfix));
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(matcherInput);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        return matcher.group();

    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Its too confusing to understand.edit the question

Comment: It isn't clear what it is that you are asking. Could you rethink your phrasing?

Comment: Okay , i will edit my question

Comment: This is just a request, not a question. Show us what you've tried, how it didn't work, some valid examples, some invalid examples, etc.

Comment: @Biffen the pattern like [A-Z]?[1-9] , first i replace ? to dot(.) .  so it should accept like a19, a.2, a89, etc.

Comment: @Biffen i want to accept like a@2, a&4... like this

Comment: @RajasekaranT What on earth are you talking about?! Do you know what a question mark means in regex? Are you saying you *have* changed it, or you *want to* change it? What are the rules of the pattern, *exactly*?

Comment: @Biffen , i want to change it, i ask u suggest, how i solve this.

Comment: @RajasekaranT To what?! *Tell us* what it should match, don't just show a few examples. It's a *really* easy task with regex, but you're making it hard by being unclear. Is the first letter optional? Which characters are allowed after the letter? How many digits at the end? No zeros? And — perhaps most important of all — *what have you tried and where are you stuck*?

Comment: @Biffen, you not understand what i am asking? again i repeating you, i give pattern like this [A-Z]?[1-9] . if user enter input a@9 (or) a&9 (or) a39 (or) aa9 it should be accept.

Comment: @Biffen , are you clear now?

Comment: @RajasekaranT I'm clear; you're not. And you have not yet asked a single *question*, just told us about some things you want. Yeah, I can see you have a pattern and a few strings that *don't* match that pattern. If you want them to match you need to *change* the pattern. This is easy, if you know what you want to match. But we don't know that, because you're not telling us. Without knowing, the answer could be anything from `.*` to `a@9|a&9|a39|aa9`. The fact that your current pattern is quite far from what you're describing does not help.

Comment: @Biffen, thanks i ll find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is either `[A-Z].[1-9]` or `[A-Z][#@1-9][1-9]`, depending on how much your middle character can vary.

Right now you're using the ? to state that `[A-Z]` can either be there or not, followed by `[1-9]`; this makes it match things like `A9` or simply `8`.